# Find following values and represent their occurences in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A`:

```
A = [23  34  45   0    0    0 ;
     21  34   0   0   23   11 ;
     34  23   0   0    0   22 ;
     23  11  21   0    0   45 ;
     11  45  23   0    0    0 ]
```

I have found the unique values in the matrix:

```
U = unique(A) = [0; 11; 21; 22; 23; 34; 45]
```

Excluding the value `0`, I want a matrix 6x6 (6 is the number of values found without zero) in which I want to represent the number of times that a value is following from another value in every row.

**For Example:**

Occurence that after `11`, there is `11` is `0`.

Occurence that after `11`, there is `21` is `1`.

Occurence that after `11`, there is `22` is `0`.

Occurence that after `11`, there is `23` is `0`.

Occurence that after `11`, there is `34` is `0`.

Occurence that after `11`, there is `45` is `1`.

So the first row of the matrix I want is: `B = [0 1 0 0 0 1]`

Occurence that after `21`, there is `11` is `0`.

Occurence that after `21`, there is `21` is `0`.

Occurence that after `21`, there is `22` is `0`.

Occurence that after `21`, there is `23` is `0`.

Occurence that after `21`, there is `34` is `1`.

Occurence that after `21`, there is `45` is `1`.

So the second row of the matrix is

```
B = [0 1 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 1 1; ...]
```

I want to repeat the same process, for all the values in `U`.

Can you help me?

Comment: it could be a lot easier if you substitute 1:6 for 11 21 etc

Comment: I have no idea how to do... I have thought to find all the possible combination of values in the matrix A but it not a smart idea

Comment: na, you want to use a `circshift(A,[0,-1])` that gives you the matrix with all the elements, you want to drop the last row of A and this matrix. combine this with A, you should end up with 5*5 or 25 sets of numbers, which like I said earlier you could convert into coordinates - (if you substitute them 1:6 you see?)

Comment: @elis56 You wrote: *"Occurence that after `21`, there is `45` is `1`"* Is that a typo? Shouldn't it be zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a possible solution:

```
A = [23  34  45   0    0    0 ;
     21  34   0   0   23   11 ;
     34  23   0   0    0   22 ;
     23  11  21   0    0   45 ;
     11  45  23   0    0    0 ]
% final result is a 6 * 6 table we want to map from 11; 21; 22; 23; 34; 45 to 1:6
% first  sort the array
[S SI] = sort(A(:));
% then generate mapped values corresponding to original values
S2=[0; (cumsum(diff(S)>0))];
% then replace original with mapped value
A(SI) = S2;
% use circshift to create a matrix that brings next element in each row to one left ,
% so current value in original matrix and next value in cricshifted matrix are in the same position.
C=circshift(A,[0,-1]);
% so both matrices converted to vectors and horizontally concatenated to a n * 2 matrix (U) ,
% its first column is the current element in each row and second column is the following element.
% since for example there may be multiple cases of [11 21] ,
% we take unique of the U matrix to remove repeated co-occurances.
U =  unique( [A(1:end-size(A,1)); C(1:end-size(A,1))]','rows');
% zero values should be discarded then we get indices of rows that contain zero
[ro ,~] = find(U == 0);
uro = unique(ro);
% rows that contain zero excluded from two column matrix (U).
U(uro,:) =[];
% now first column of U contains indices of rows of 1s and second column indices of their columns.
% then convert indices to 0-1 matrix
result = full(sparse(U(:,1),U(:,2),1))
```

Comment: Also add some explanation to make it easier to understand

Comment: I think this is a great answer, and it should be super fast as well (all parallelized functions).

Comment: @Sardar_Usama explanation provided

Comment: @GameOfThrows cheers. there may be better solutions. I saw your comment under the question but after i have completed my answer. your idea specially about cirshift is interesting

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo somewhere in here since I'm working sans-compiler, but general strategy is: Create Mask, Apply Mask, Count

```
U = U(2:end); %Remove 0 value from unique matrix

output = zeros(length(U));

for ii = 1:length(U)
    maskA = cumsum(A == U(ii),2); #Find any values of A = U(ii), and make them + all to the right equal to 1
    maskA = [zeros(size(A,1),1) maskA(:,1:size(A,2)-1)] %Shift highlighting to the right one column
    maskedA = A*maskA; %Filter out only values we want to count
    for kk = 2:length(U)
        output(ii,jj) = sum(maskedA(:)==U(ii)); %Count number of matching values
    end
end
```